# Dash/Plotly app throwing Heroku R10 Error even when $PORT is set

Tags: python, heroku, plotly-dash

I have a web app I made with Dash that deployed to Docker properly using my dockerfile and I was trying to upload this container to the web using Heroku. I keep getting the error R10, that it failed to bind to $PORT within a timeout and I'm really confused on what I'm doing wrong.

Currently this is the Dash/Heroku portion I have.

```
ON_HEROKU = os.environ.get('ON_HEROKU')
if ON_HEROKU:
   port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 8070))  # as per OP comments default is 17995
else:
   port = 8070

...

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
server = app.server

...

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run_server(host='0.0.0.0', port=port, debug=True, use_reloader=True)
```

My dockerfile looks like this:

```
# Use the official lightweight Python image.

# https://hub.docker.com/_/python

FROM python:3.9-slim-buster

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install nano
RUN mkdir wd
WORKDIR wd
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . ./

CMD \[ "gunicorn", "-b 0.0.0.0:8070", "app:server"]
```

My heroku.yml file just points to my Dockerfile

```
build:
   docker:     
      web: Dockerfile
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong with the port or setting it in my dockerfile that it's not binding correctly to the port? Or could there be other things at play like the requirements file (odd if it's working on Docker?) Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!